# Deriving the inequalities in potential theory

Tags: calculus, inequality, definite-integrals, mathematical-physics, potential-theory

I am reading the following pages from my book on "[foundations of potential theory](http://lib1.org/_ads/48AEFC4C49281110D30CB1A8F1FFE9A9)" page 150/151:

[image]

[image]

I understand up to inequality $(4)$. I can't derive inequality $(5)$ from $(4)$. **Please derive inequalities from $(5)$ to $(7)$.**

> **EDIT: (Statement of continuity)**
>
> If for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > \sqrt{(x-x_o)^2+(y-y_o)^2+(z-z_o)^2} > 0$ such that $\epsilon > \left| f(x,y,z) - f(x_0,y_0,z_0)  \right| > 0 $, then $f(x,y,z)$ is continuous at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$
>
> **How is this statement equivalent to equation $(5)$**?

Comment: Equation $(5)$ is not something one derives here, rather it is a statement of continuity of the function $\frac1r$ for $r\ne 0$.  That is all.

Comment: Equation $(5)$ doesn't imply continuity, it is a statement of continuity.

Comment: A function $f$ is continuous at $\vec r_0$ if for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a deleted neighborhood of $\vec r_0$ such that whenever $\vec r$ is in that deleted neighborhood, $|f(\vec r)-f(\vec r_0)|<\epsilon$.  That is effectively Equation $5$ with $f=1/r=1/|\vec r|$.  The term $3BV$ is included for convenience.

Comment: "Then $U$ is continuous at $P_0$ and hence throughout space"... Does this continuity theorem also apply at the boundary of $V$? It doesn't seem to me because at the boundary of $V$, we can't choose $\sigma$. Can we?

Comment: For points at the boundary, the excluding region $\sigma$ will not be a sphere.

Comment: I do not think it is necessary for $\sigma$ to be a sphere even when checking the continuity of a point inside $V$. Is it so?

Comment: You're correct.  For the case at the boundary, all points of the excluding region are also in V.

Comment: "all points of the excluding region are also in $V$" Why? Should'nt we approach $\vec{r}_0$ from all directions? We need to show $U$ is continuous all over the space.

Comment: Please explain in an answer what shall we do to show that $U$ is continuous at boundary points.Naively, due to the discontinuity in density $\chi$, it seems to me that $U$ is discontinuous at boundary points.